# JDialog Close button event

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

For my custom `JDialog`,

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

has been set.

There is a button on the `JDialog`. Based on a condition, it calls `dialog.dispose()`.

Both these actions trigger the `windowClosed` event. But I want to identify it reached there because the close button was clicked or because the dispose method was invoked.

Comment: Can't you just set a flag in your dialog class?

Comment: What do you get from `event.getSource()`?

Comment: Add an `ActionListener` to your button?

Answer (score 6):

Add a `WindowListener` to the `JDialog`, and on `windowClosed` set a boolean or something when it is closed. Also have a `buttonClicked` boolean, if they clicked the button it would be true, if they clicked the exit button at the top of the window it would be false.

```
boolean closed;
boolean buttonClicked;
JButton exitbutton;
JDialog dialog;
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    buttonClicked = true;
    dialog.dispose();
}
...
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    closed = true;
                    if(buttonClicked) {
                    //They cliked the button to close it.
                    } else {
                    // They didn't click the button, they clicked exit in the top right corner of screen.
                    }
                }
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    // Do nothing
                }

            });
```